# Run a background job every few seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, resque

Say I have an application that needs to pull data from an API, but that there is a limit to how often I can send a query (i.e., caps at X requests / minute). In order to ensure I don't hit this limit, I want to add requests to a queue, and have a background job that will pull X requests and execute it every minute. I'm not sure what's the best method for this in Rails, however. From what I gather, DelayedJob is the better library for my needs, but I don't see any support for only running X jobs a minute. Does anyone know if there is a preferred way of implementing functionality like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try [whenever]: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Then you can add your tasks as bellow:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

in a schedule.rb file

Comment: Whenever use cron and cron cant use less than every 1minute

Answer (score 7):

I'm a little late but I would like to warn against using the `whenever` gem in your situation:
Since you're using Ruby on Rails, using the whenever gem will be loading the environment each time it gets called in cron.

Give [`rufus-scheduler`](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/two/README.rdoc) a try.

Place the code below, for example, in `config/initializers/cron_stuff.rb`

```
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.every '20m' do
  puts 'hello'
end
```

Comment: If we need to interact with the database to store the information from the API results, we'd be loading up the environment each time right? Or would `whenever` still be a little too much overhead for that?

Comment: Whenever creates a system "cron" entry for you that would call something like "`rails console`" (you know how slow that is) every time, which will load up the environment every time. The easiest solution is to have the rufus-scheduler code above run during your application's initialization which would avoid loading the environment and db connections every time. Of course there are better approaches such as creating a rake task that has the rufus-scheduler inside (especially if you are running on multiple servers, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend using [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) for processing background jobs.  It's well supported and very simple to use.  If you do use Sidekiq, then there is another gem, called [Sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq), that will allow you to run recurring jobs.